# What is OpenGL's method for assigning texture IDs?

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have a function that loads a texture, and returns the newly generated `GLuint`. I need to know what I should return if it fails to load the texture. So if `glGenTextures` starts assigning texture IDs at 1, I could return `GL_FALSE`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's implementation-defined.

You do not need to know, nor should you *care*, how the implementation allocates names (or IDs, as you call them) for *any* object. You are expected only to keep track of the integer that represents the object, so that you can bind it, and free it when you're done with it.

If you are not already keeping track of the number as representing a texture, then you can always call `glIsTexture()` to find out.

`glGenTextures` will not fail to provide new names unless system memory has been exhausted. A name of `0` will *never* be used, and is a reserved name for textures. All names will be nonzero, unsigned integers.

Comment: I did. Twice. Your question is unclear. I will amend my answer, but please rewrite your question with more specificity.

Comment: @Jay: Your actual question is hidden among a lot of more or less irrelevant hand-wringing. More *specificity* will help. That is, if you *specify* what you mean by "fails to load the texture," with detail, it's far easier to understand why you think you need to know the allocation scheme for `glGenTextures`.

Comment: @Jay: your specific question (in title) is answered here. It also mentions that 0 would work as a failure code, but really, nothing says you should be able to store failure in the GLuint... @greyfade: real nitpicking: glGenTextures does not return positive, nonzero integers, it returns nonzero unsigned integers. (ie. only 1 value out of the 2^integer_bit_width is invalid). Point being, -1 would not work as an invalid return value.

Answer (score 1):

This answers your question:

[Is 0 a valid OpenGL texture ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108589/is-0-a-valid-opengl-texture-id)

Comment: thanks, that solves my problem. but it still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Jay, I think the answer to your question is it depends on the implementation

Comment: I've seen cases where texture 0 was assigned an internal default texture (like pure white, for example).

Comment: @Jim, well if that's true, it invalidates the other answer. It REALLY depends on the openGL implementation then.

Comment: well, it would still work in my case. all that matters for me is that `glGenTextures` doesn't return 0.

Comment: @Dominic - Well, I wouldn't say it invalidates the other answer, which says it's reserved. Reserved for what is the question. In some cases (i.e. depending on the implementation), it's reserved and used for a default texture.

Comment: @Jim, that's true. I hadn't looked at it like that.